# Trop of tvir and dargah

Tags: trop-cantillation

Aside from Sedra Miketz, is there another place in Chumash where a dargah is not followed by a tvir within 3 words?

Comment: Where in Miketz?

Comment: 41:3: שבע פרות אחרות.

Comment: Its *often* followed by a רביע

Answer (score 5):

Lots of places. It is true that darga is usually the servitor (meshares) of tevir, but it's not exclusively so. It can also precede munach and revi'i (e.g., Gen. 41:3 and Num. 4:12,14), and (rarely) mercha-kefulah and tipcha (e.g., Gen. 27:25).

Comment: Thanks. So much for my opus. I had noticed that the Haftorah also had a case of darga not followed by tevir.

Comment: last posuk of matos has a darga before mercha-kefulah.

Comment: Yeah, both of those are among the fourteen times in Tanach that mercha-kefulah appears. All of them are preceded by darga and followed by tipcha.

Comment: @Alex In Kings 1:20:29, it's not followed by a tipcha.